# How can I upload images through an webView application android .. This is my application

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to upload images through a web view application.

This is my manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

and this is my homecode code

```
package com.zoorne.zoorne;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_LOCATIION=1;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        getLocation();

        double latti=0.0;
        double longi=0.0;

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATIION);
        }else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(location != null){
                 latti=location.getLatitude();
                 longi=location.getLongitude();
            }

        }

        webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);//added to day
        webSettings.getAllowFileAccess();//added to day
        webSettings.getAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs();//added to day
        webSettings.getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs();//added to day
        webSettings.getLoadsImagesAutomatically();//added to day

        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://something`enter code here`.com?type=android&tp=app&lat="+latti+"&long="+longi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    public void getLocation(){

    }

}
```

and this is my html

```
<input type="file" id="inputfilecar" name="inputfile" accept="image/*" capture="capture">
```

Comment: You can try this link, using the Retrofit library or Ion. I have never done this form so you can try and give the results.
https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-upload-image-to-mysql-server-using-retrofit-and-ion-in-android-observer-pattern-part-1-51c2340241c0

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You can edit your question to demonstrate what you have done to solve the problem and what specific errors/problems you are having but I have flagged this as too broad at the moment and it may well be removed. Don't be disheartened if it is removed, it just means you need to be more focussed on the question you are asking, so try and ask again!  Good luck.